# How to vertical align the fraction choice in quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

the view of choices on my quiz is like this [choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Jhg.png) ,
looks untidy

I want, the view of choices on my quiz is like this
[choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTzW2.png) ,
where the radio buttons align with the center of each selection.

I've added `vertical-align: middle` to the `label` and `.multipleChoiceQues` in CSS, but the appearance hasn't changed.
this is my MSE

```js
var $progressValue = 0;
var resultList = [];
const quizdata = [{
    question: "Find the value of <div class='frac'><span>4<sup>3</sup> &times 4<sup>2</sup> &times 4<sup>-4</sup></span><span class='symbol'>/</span><span class='bottom'>4<sup>2</sup></span></div>",
    options: ["<div class='frac'><span>1</span><span class='symbol'>/</span><span class='bottom'>4</span></div>", "<div class='frac'><span>1</span><span class='symbol'>/</span><span class='bottom'>2</span></div>", "1", "4"],
    answer: "<div class='frac'><span>1</span><span class='symbol'>/</span><span class='bottom'>4</span></div>",
    category: 1
  }
];
/** Random shuffle questions **/
function shuffleArray(question) {
  var shuffled = question.sort(function() {
    return .5 - Math.random();
  });
  return shuffled;
}



/*** Return shuffled question ***/
function generateQuestions() {
  var questions = shuffleArray(quizdata);
  return questions;
}

/*** Return list of options ***/
function returnOptionList(opts, i) {

  var optionHtml = '<li class="myoptions">' +
    '<input value="' + opts + '" name="optRdBtn" type="radio" id="rd_' + i + '">' +
    '<label for="rd_' + i + '">' + opts + '</label>' +
    '<div class="bullet">' +
    '<div class="line zero"></div>' +
    '<div class="line one"></div>' +
    '<div class="line two"></div>' +
    '<div class="line three"></div>' +
    '<div class="line four"></div>' +
    '<div class="line five"></div>' +
    '<div class="line six"></div>' +
    '<div class="line seven"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';

  return optionHtml;
}

/** Render Options **/
function renderOptions(optionList) {
  var ulContainer = $('<ul>').attr('id', 'optionList');
  for (var i = 0, len = optionList.length; i < len; i++) {
    var optionContainer = returnOptionList(optionList[i], i)
    ulContainer.append(optionContainer);
  }
  $(".answerOptions").html('').append(ulContainer);
}

/** Render question **/
function renderQuestion(question) {
  $(".question").html("<h1>" + question + "</h1>");
}

/** Render quiz :: Question and option **/
function renderQuiz(questions, index) {
  var currentQuest = questions[index];
  renderQuestion(currentQuest.question);
  renderOptions(currentQuest.options);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var presentIndex = 0;
  var clicked = 0;

  var questions = generateQuestions();
  renderQuiz(questions, presentIndex);
  getProgressindicator(questions.length);
 
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
.quizArea{
  width: 95%;
 margin:  auto;
 padding:10px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 }
.multipleChoiceQues{
  width:90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.question{
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 220px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height:30px;
}
label{
    color: #7f8280;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
label:before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #7f8280;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
        top: calc(50% - 13px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bullet {   
    position: relative; 
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    left: -3px;
    top: 2px;
    border: 5px solid #fff ;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #00ffee;
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: explode;
    animation-duration: 0.350s;
}


.frac {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    text-align: center;
}
.frac > span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.1em;
}
.frac span.bottom {
    border-top: thin solid black;
}
.frac span.symbol {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@7.2.0/dist/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="quizArea" id="pertanyaan">
  <div class="multipleChoiceQues">
    <h1 class="mc_quiz">
      Quiz
    </h1>
    
    <div class="quizBox">
      <div class="question"> </div>
      <div class="answerOptions"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
 
  </div>
```

Which parts of the CSS need fixing so that it looks the way I expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below CSS to your code :

```css
#optionList .frac {
  top: -0.75em;
}
```